# XMPP - How to login via scanning QR code

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, xmpp, qr-code

In my setup, users have an XMPP chat app installed on their phones, and are already logged in. There is also a javascript web-based version of the app that users may login to via scanning a QR code. My question is, after scanning the QR code and confirming who they are, how can I login from the web-based app?

Currently, the flow of events is like this:

1. Login on their phone
2. Open the web app. Web app receives a unique key, which is what the QR code will be generated from. The unique key is only valid for 30
   seconds.
3. Scan the QR code from the phone app; The unique key is then sent to the server from the phone, and because the phone session is already
   authenticated, they can now log in via the web app.
4. The web app receives a response from the server to log in.

But on step 4, how can I log the user in? I assume sending the username and password from the server to the client, and then just letting the client login normally, is a terrible idea, but I am not sure how to authenticate any other way in order to log the user in.

Comment: When you generate the unique key you could bind it to the user in the database, so it can be used as verification for the user?

Comment: @Jesper Yes, but I mean specifically how can I authenticate the session on the web app? As far as I know, an XMPP session is authenticated only when the user sends their username and password in an <auth></auth> stanza. Id prefer the web app to have no need for the password to authenticate.